# What Shape Key affects a certain vertex (what Shape Keys is a vertex influenced by)?

Tags: python, shape-keys

I am trying to find what Shape Keys might be (incorrectly) influencing a vertex on my character mesh, an example might be an index finger that influences an ankle vertex.

I see how I can select a vertex and discover its membership in one or more Vertex Groups:

[image]

and if I visit any Shape Key driver I might see a bone that is used in the Shape Key evaluation:

[image]

and if there was a Vertex Group listed in the Shape Key VG influence that could be helpful, but you'll see here I don't see these in my imported (DAZ) character.

[image]

Is there some way to ask "from what Shape Key(s) is this vertex position changed"?   Perhaps there is a python scripting solution?

Due to the "All uploaded files must be in the blend file format" I must use a [dropbox link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/pz56z9smsxbhsle/rigged_vertex_problem.blend?dl=0) instead of blend-exchange.com for my example blend file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All vertices are affected by all shapekeys.  They might not be moved by a particular shapekey-- the shapekey might have a vector of 0,0,0 for any particular vertex-- but it's not like some vertices are assigned to shapekeys and others aren't.

Likewise, your mesh is deformed by the sum of *all* shapekeys.  There may be just one shapekey responsible, or there may be more than one.

However, you can be pretty sure that shapekeys with a value of 0.000 are not responsible for the deformation (although it could be 0.0001 on a really extreme shapekey); you should start by looking at shapekeys with values like 1.0 or so.

A good way to inspect your shapekeys is to use the pin icon on the shapekeys tab-- the button that looks like a pushpin.  This will show your model with the selected shapekey at full strength, and without any other shapekeys affecting the model.  Then, you can just leave that pin button set and select succeeding shapekeys (perhaps with down arrow), looking for anything that isn't what you expect.